# Sending GCode as String Using Java

Tags: java, jssc, g-code

Writing a simple program to send GCode via Java using jssc libraries.
Tried the following without success

- serialPort.writeString("G01 X1 Y1 Z1")
- serialPort.writeString("%G01 X1 Y1 Z1%")
- serialPort.writeString("%")
  serialPort.writeString("G01 X1 Y1 Z1")
  serialPort.writeString("%")

I am able to open / close the port (can hear the pulse from the machine) but the machine wont react to the Gcode sent.
Need help.

Regards,
Jai

Comment: Perhaps try adding a **Carraige Return / Linefeed** combination to the end of each string: `serialPort.writeString("G01 X1 Y1 Z1\r\n";`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion.. Tried it, did not work unfortunately.